# What kind of impact does applying all these Scala traits have at runtime?

Tags: scala, traits

Imagine this:

```
val myObject = if(someCondition) {
    new Whatever with Trait1
} else if(otherCondition) {
    new Whatever with Trait2 with Trait3 with Trait4
} else {
    new Whatever with Trait5
}
```

Is the `myObject` object "composed" at runtime, or is the scala compiler smart enough to generate the appropriate code at compile time? What kind of performance impact will it have on the code if you have multiple places that are applying traits like in the above code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's composed at compile-time

The traits will be added as interfaces to the resulting type, and any concrete methods from those traits will (usually) be copied to the class in their entirety.

Occasionally, the compiler may have to provide concrete implementations via forwarders to static methods, but this isn't usually the case.

Comment: My addition(s): It's the price to pay for living in a Single Inheritance (SI) Java World: Traits must be *baked in* because there is no way to adjust the SI Method Resolution Order (MRO). (This is similar to traits in Squeak ST but much different than traits in Ruby which actually do alter the MRO). This also means that changing a trait without recompiling the module using the trait can lead to some rather interesting situations... then again, the same can be argued for normal classes.

Answer (score 6):

Scala will create three anonymous classes, (except the last condition is a syntax error).

Note: These classes will be named using the *order* in which they are defined in the scope they are defined.   So...  OuterClass$anon$1 -> 3.   Please avoid using these anonymous classes in any long-term Java-serialization as this locks down the order of anonymous classes in your code.

Other than that, it's an awesome convenience feature!